# Unitary matrix and invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is every unitary matrix invertible?

I think the statement is true? It seems like I can't find a counter example.

Comment: If $AB$ is invertible and $A,B$ are square then $A,B$ are invertible,

Answer (score 2):

The definition of "unitary" implies that unitary matrices are invertible: the inverse is its conjugate transpose.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is true. One way to see it that $Q^*Q=I$ implies $detQ \neq 0$. Another way is that the column vectors of $Q$ are orthogonal in complex way (I mean $u^*v=0$), so they have to be linearly independent. So $Q$ is invertible.